# LibreOffice Writer inconsistent units: lines & inches

Tags: libreoffice, style

I've been formatting documents in LibreOffice and am really confused by the inconsistent usage of units in its styles - I refer to the paragraph styles editing dialog.

Often, when I try to edit a style, the units become weird - sometimes, I see inches used as the units, but other times, I see lines used as the units.

[image: Lines as units picture]
[image: Inches as units picture]

My question:

- Why does LibreOffice switch between these units?
- When does it use inches and when does it use lines (or is it a bug)?
- How can I make sure only one unit is used while I edit a document (because it gets really annoying to see my units suddenly change and the entire document gets messy)?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of liberoffice ?

Comment: @Pandya 4.2.5.2 build 420m0

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Tools>Options** (Then LibreOffice Writer - General).
Here is Screen-shot for selecting Measurement unit:

[image: screen]

Comment: This is not my problem, though, because it's switching between inches and lines, not centimeters, etc. - and it switches without reason.

Comment: @KyeWShi I think for Double Line spacing, it measures in line.

Comment: This setting does not affect the paragraph dialog at all, unfortunately. I haven't find any way to use millimeters there!